# Проверить наличие мутации или действия в VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Как можно проверить наличие мутации или действия в хранилище vuex?
Хотелось бы, конечно иметь что то вроде такого, но не нашел:

Например из компонента

```
this.$store.has('commit','MUTATION_NAME')
```

Или из самого хранилища, из действия

```
actions: {
   SET_CURRENT_ACCOUNT (context, payload) {
     context.has('dispatch','ACTION_NAME')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const module1 = {
  state: {
    name: "Ivan"
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_NAME: (state, payload) => {
      state.name = payload;
    }
  }
};
const module2 = {
  state: {
    age: 10
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_AGE: (state, payload) => {
      state.age = payload;
    }
  }
};
const store = new Vuex.Store({ modules: { module1, module2 } });
store.checkMutation = function(name) {
  return Object.keys(this._mutations).includes(name);
};

new Vue({
  store,
  el: "#app",
  created() {
    console.log(this.$store.checkMutation("SET_NAME"));
    console.log(this.$store.checkMutation("TEST"));
  }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.0.0"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>
```